# Access Not Configured Android Google API Key

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-api-java-client, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use Youtube Data API v3 to search on android, though when I try to search using my API key i always get this message:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}
```

I have the Youtube Data API set to on in my Console. I have been trying to figure this out for hours. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A bit mind confusing is that for the YouTube Data API you need to use the browser-key, but for the YouTube Player API (for Android) you need the Android-key.

Using the Android key for the YouTube Data API will not work and result in the error you received.

Comment: The same with iOS! iOS-key doesn't work but Browser Key works. What's wrong with Google? Got almost crazy trying to make it work.

Comment: I know the Android key can be used for the YouTube Player API (for Android), but what function the iOS key has...

Comment: This should be put somewhere clear, because I'm sure a ton of developers will have that issue.

Comment: a little? my god I've lost 3 hours today! Thank you very much @PieterAelse !

Comment: LOL.  I seriously can't believe this worked.  Google--

Answer (score 6):

I've finally solved this. I deleted my project and created a new project in the old Cloud Console. I then activated all the APIs I need to use and then went into API Access and there was a key already there. It should say "Key for browser apps (with referers)" and I just used that key, and it works.

Comment: Thanks. This also solved partially my issue. What I noticed as difference between key generated using new console and old console:
 - new console generated key contains "-" char inside key
 - old console generated key doesn't contain "-" char inside key

Maybe this is the issue :)

Comment: I spent too much time trying to get this to work. The old Cloud Console and default "Key for browser apps (with referers)" did the trick.  Very frustrating...  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

It's a very late reply but the issue was very hard to detect. I tried a lot of solutions but nothing was working for me. The only solution works in my case is to generate new `API_KEY` from google API console.