# Right way to use YouTube.Builder

Tags: android, scala, youtube-api

I need to get user youtube videos. Here is my code which only tries to get user youtube channels. But it does not work - after choosing account, *loadYoutubeChannels* always thows errors. I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21407747/5468694) and this [yt-direct-lite-android](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/ytdl), but still don't understand why they do not get errors, but i get. 

Here is my code:

```
class YotubeTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private var credential: GoogleAccountCredential = _
  private var service: YouTube = _

  override def onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle): Unit = {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, List(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_READONLY))
    credential.setSelectedAccountName(prefs.getString(PrefAccountName, None.orNull))

    val transport = new NetHttpTransport()
    val factory =  new JacksonFactory()

    service = new YouTube.Builder(transport, factory, credential)
      .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name))
      .setYouTubeRequestInitializer(new YouTubeRequestInitializer(ApiKey)) // <-- (1)
      .build()
  }

  /*
  check for Google Play Service

  choose account
   */

  private def onAccountChooseOk(accountName: String): Unit = {
    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName)

    val prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
    prefs.putString(PrefAccountName, accountName)
    prefs.commit()

    rxScalaRunInBackground(loadYoutubeChannels, onLoadYoutubeChannelsOk, onLoadYoutubeChannelsError)
  }

  private def loadYoutubeChannels(): ChannelListResponse = {
    val channelsQuery = service.channels().list("contentDetails")
    channelsQuery.setMine(true)
    channelsQuery.setMaxResults(50l)
    //channelsQuery.setKey(ApiKey)  // <-- (2)
    channelsQuery.execute()
  }

  private def onLoadYoutubeChannelsError(e: Throwable): Unit = {
    Log.e(Tag, "onLoadYoutubeChannelsError", e)

    e match {
      case _: GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException => // checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable()
      case e: UserRecoverableAuthIOException => // startActivityForResult(e.getIntent, RequestAuthorization);
      case _ => finish()
    }
  }

  private def onLoadYoutubeChannelsOk(response: ChannelListResponse): Unit = {
    Log.e(Tag, s"onLoadYoutubeChannelsOk: $response")
  }

}

object YotubeTestActivity {

  private val Tag = "YotubeTestActivity"    
  private val PrefAccountName = "accountName"    
  private val ApiKey = "API_KAY_FROM_DEV_CONSOLE"

}
```

When i do not use *ApiKey*, i mean when **(1)** and **(2)** is commented, i get this error:

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 608941808256 bef$re or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/overview?project=608941808256 then r$try. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "reason" : "accessNotConfigured",
    "extendedHelp" : "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/overview?project=60894180$256"
  } ],
  "message" : "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 608941808256 befor$ or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/overview?project=608941808256 then ret$y. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
}
```

When i use *browser key* or [api key](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#create_project), i get this error:

```
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

As far as i understood *yt-direct-lite-android* use *ApiKey* only in *YouTubePlayerFragment*, but not when fetching some youtube data (channels, etc). So.. it's unfair.

Can someone tell what i'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

Open [google developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)

Go to *Credentials/OAuth consent screen*. Fill *Product name shown to users*. And also put it here:

```
service = new YouTube.Builder(transport, factory, credential)
  .setApplicationName(/*Product name shown to users*/)
```

Next step - register your app. Go to *Credentials/credentials* and click button *Create credentials* then choose *OAuth Client ID* and then choose *Android* and put your application SHA1 there.

Last step - create api key. In *Credentials/credentials* click button *Create credentials* and choose *API key* and then choos **Browser key**. Then use this generated browser key here.

```
private val ApiKey = "/*Browser key*/"
```