# android keep the reference to old google api project

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, accountmanager, unauthorized

I am working with YouTube google api and I have this error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
04-15 13:25:42.951 22653-24865/com.player.jointv W/System.err: {
04-15 13:25:42.951 22653-24865/com.player.jointv W/System.err:   "code" : 403,
04-15 13:25:42.951 22653-24865/com.player.jointv W/System.err:   "errors" : [ {
04-15 13:25:42.951 22653-24865/com.player.jointv W/System.err:     "domain" : "usageLimits",
04-15 13:25:42.951 22653-24865/com.player.jointv W/System.err:     "message" : "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project XXXXXXXXXXXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/overview?project=XXXXXXXXXXXX then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
04-15 13:25:42.951 22653-24865/com.player.jointv W/System.err:     "reason" : "accessNotConfigured",
04-15 13:25:42.951 22653-24865/com.player.jointv W/System.err:     "extendedHelp" : "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/overview?project=XXXXXXXXXXXX"
04-15 13:25:42.951 22653-24865/com.player.jointv W/System.err:   } ],
04-15 13:25:42.951 22653-24865/com.player.jointv W/System.err:   "message" : "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project XXXXXXXXXXXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/overview?project=XXXXXXXXXXXX then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
04-15 13:25:42.951 22653-24865/com.player.jointv W/System.err: }
```

I thought that my problem was with an disable api or maybe using a wrong username but then I click on the project reference in the error and I saw that the project ID (XXXXXXXXXXXX) is wrong because it was an old project.

### The problems are:

- I don't know how to update or what do I need to change in order to
  get the new project ID??
- Do I need to remove any trash file??
- Where or how android project keep these references? I am worry about that because if I need to remove the current project maybe I will get the same error in the future.

### Tools.

Using Android Studio 2.0 on Windows.

### Get the Auth Token

I get the token using ***GoogleAuthUtils***:

```
token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, account, Config.YOUTUBE_SCOPES);
```

Where:

**context**: AppCompatActivity

**account**: Account

**Config.YOUTUBE_SCOPES**:

```
final String YOUTUBE_SCOPES = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly" +
            " https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly";
```

### Creating Credentials

I took this peace of code from [Google Credential example](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#credential):

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential()
                                  .setAccessToken(authToken);
```

### Using credential to configure the api services.

```
// This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests.
youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("youtube-analytics-api-report-example")
                    .build();

//This object is used to make YouTube Analytics API requests.
analytics = new YouTubeAnalytics
                .Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName("youtube-analytics-api-report-example")
                .build();
```

### Using a web API KEY

I create a web api key and I got the error:

```
04-15 15:36:27.274 14733-16676/com.player.jointv W/System.err: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
04-15 15:36:27.274 14733-16676/com.player.jointv W/System.err: {
04-15 15:36:27.274 14733-16676/com.player.jointv W/System.err:   "code" : 401,
04-15 15:36:27.274 14733-16676/com.player.jointv W/System.err:   "errors" : [ {
04-15 15:36:27.274 14733-16676/com.player.jointv W/System.err:     "domain" : "global",
04-15 15:36:27.274 14733-16676/com.player.jointv W/System.err:     "location" : "Authorization",
04-15 15:36:27.274 14733-16676/com.player.jointv W/System.err:     "locationType" : "header",
04-15 15:36:27.274 14733-16676/com.player.jointv W/System.err:     "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
04-15 15:36:27.274 14733-16676/com.player.jointv W/System.err:     "reason" : "authError"
04-15 15:36:27.274 14733-16676/com.player.jointv W/System.err:   } ],
04-15 15:36:27.274 14733-16676/com.player.jointv W/System.err:   "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
04-15 15:36:27.274 14733-16676/com.player.jointv W/System.err: }
```

What is happen? I feel bad?

Comment: Perhaps you could check the youtube_api_key is the correct key or old one?

Comment: @Elye I create the project from scratch and generate a new OAuth2 key. I am using `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, account, scopes)` to get the token in order to use it to get the data. I don't know why or where is that old reference ??

Comment: I don't recall playing YouTubeApi need any OAuth login. Perhaps you need to go to your Google Developer console to enable your app to make YouTubeApi call?

Comment: For the YouTube Player no, but I want to access to my channel data and also information. These kind of process require and OAuth2 authorization. Allow/Deny access. Well, I don't know where is the problem in my code or android access. I am using a token to access to my channel information. If a resolve the project id problem I will be happy.

Comment: The error seems more YoutubeApi related than OAuth. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582274/right-way-to-use-youtube-builder

Comment: Have you enable your app to access the YouTubeApi in your Google Developer Console?

Comment: Check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Im69kzhpR3I

Comment: Yes I had enabled the apis.

Comment: Was it solved with that? If not, I guess you'll have to divide and conquer to find the culprit.

Comment: Can you confirm that your Gradle script / Manifest file do not have that old package name any where ?

Comment: Hello @Sam, I also create a new project with a new OAuth2 ID and I did everything from scratch and the message is the same and with the same old project ID. I don't know where is the problem?

Comment: It is really strange but I would recommend to change everything. Try using other developer account not the account which you used to register the old package.

Comment: Have you tried this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318585/youtube-api-com-google-api-client-googleapis-json-googlejsonresponseexception